# How can I apply the changes made in app.json? update splash screen in my expo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, android-splashscreen

I am trying to change my default Splash screen in my Expo app with a new one. I am using EAS profile development.

this is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "blue-kiwi",
    "slug": "blue-kiwi",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.basselturky.bluekiwi"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png" 
    }
  }
}
```

I put my new splash.png in the assets folder but it keeps showing the default one.

I tried to rebuild but nothing worked.

I want to be able to change it whenever I want and the splash updates instantly.

Comment: Have you rebuild your development if yes. Then you have to install the new updates to your devices/emulator